# Chrome failed to start: exited normally

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am following the solution in this post:

[C# selenium chrome driver, every time I run my program I need to scan QR code from my mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75255913/c-sharp-selenium-chrome-driver-every-time-i-run-my-program-i-need-to-scan-qr-co/76114567)

The code I tried:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox") 
options.AddArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-using")
options.AddArguments("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
options.AddArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 1"); // <-- substitute Profile 3 with your profile name
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
```

But getting the following error:

[image]

> {"unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.\n (chrome
> not reachable)\n (The process started from chrome location C:\Program
> Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so
> ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)"}

I am using:

- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver v112.0.5615.4900
- Selenium.WebDriver v4.9.0
- Selenium.Support v4.9.0
- Google Chrome v112.0.5615

Although the selected profile is opened in the browser. But for some reason it's considering it as closed and not able to communicate with it. Any insights would be highly appreciated.

It works if I close Chrome, but if Chrome is open (even with a different profile), the error shows.

Comment: Even though you are following a solution from another answer, you still need to include a [repro] consisting of your own code. Can you [edit] your question to include this information?

Comment: Furthermore, which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver do you have?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Updated the question with more details

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Chrome v112.0.5615

Comment: I added that to your question. For the future, please make sure this information is in the question, not just in comments.

Comment: If you remove all of the arguments, what happens?

Comment: Is something already running on port 9222? Try killing all remaining ChromeDriver processes, and even Chrome.exe processes.

Comment: @GregBurghardt It works properly if I close Chrome browser. But if Chrome is open even with a different profile, it doesn't work. Any clues how to deal with that so that it works even if Chrome is already open?

Comment: That's interesting. I'm not sure, offhand.

Comment: I close all Chrome windows and just run code, it's ok